# Keyset pagination with ordering in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using keyset pagination to paginate in a table. Table looks like this:

```
+-------------------------+
| ID | Name | private_key |
+-------------------------+
| 1  | John | null        |
| 2  | James| abc123      |
| 3  | Jane | null        |
| 4  | Dave | def456      |
| 5  | Will | null        |
| ...                     |
+-------------------------+
```

I'm using the ID field for the keyset pagination.

I fetch 50 records per time. After every fetch, I get the highest ID in the result set. When I fetch the next 50 results, I fetch the first 50 results AFTER this ID. An example:

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    private_key
FROM
    users
WHERE
    id > [last_id_fetched]
LIMIT
    50
```

This works perfectly. The problem is, if I use an ORDER statement, the ORDER statement is only applied to the 50 results that are fetched, not the total result set.

I have about 2,000 records, and about 500 of them have a private_key. I want to paginate with keyset pagination on the ID, but I want to fetch all the users where the private_key field is not null first.

How can I achieve this in postgres?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve keyset pagination in PostgreSQL while ensuring that rows with a non-null `private_key` are fetched first, you can use a combination of subqueries and a custom sorting strategy. Here's how you can do it:

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    private_key
FROM
    users
WHERE
    private_key IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    private_key ASC, id ASC
LIMIT
    50;

-- After fetching the above 50 results, get the last private_key and id from the result set.

SELECT
    id,
    name,
    private_key
FROM
    users
WHERE
    private_key IS NULL
AND (
    private_key > [last_private_key_fetched]
    OR (private_key = [last_private_key_fetched] AND id > [last_id_fetched])
)
ORDER BY
    private_key ASC, id ASC
LIMIT
    50;
```

In the first query, you fetch the first 50 rows where `private_key` is not null, sorted by `private_key` and then `id`. After fetching these results, note the last `private_key` and `id`.

In the second query, you fetch the next 50 rows where `private_key` is null and use a combination of sorting by `private_key` and then `id`. The `WHERE` clause ensures that you continue fetching results after the last `private_key` and `id` values obtained in the first query.

This way, you will paginate using keyset pagination on the `ID`, while ensuring that rows with non-null `private_key` values are fetched first.

Comment: The OP is paginating using `id`, not `private_key`.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use [OFFSET and FETCH FIRST](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-fetch/) for your pagination.

It's very simple to use:

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    private_key
FROM
    users
ORDER BY name
OFFSET :page_size*:page_number ROWS 
FETCH FIRST :page_size ROW ONLY
```

Or, whithout variables, if we need to populate second page with 5 rows on the each page:

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    private_key
FROM
    users
ORDER BY name
OFFSET 5*2 ROWS 
FETCH FIRST 5 ROW ONLY
```

Some exaple for playing: https://dbfiddle.uk/zplwAj9A

Answer (score 0):

If you are paginating sorting by `id` then you need to use `ORDER BY` with this column. Now, it seems you also want to filter out the rows with empty `private_key`. If that's the case then you can do:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE private_key is not null -- filter out unwanted rows
  AND id > [last_id_fetched] -- defines where the current result set starts
ORDER BY id -- make sure the pages are sorted correctly
LIMIT 50 -- defines the page size
```

To improve performance you can add the index:

```
create index ix1 on users (id) where private_key is not null;
```